# Can't print variable or assign variable in an if statement

Tags: python

I'm learning python and am doing a simple calculator. I can get and store the numbers and the operator, but can't print out the result. I tried declaring `answr` outside of the if statement, printing it outside the if statement but it still doesn't work.

```py
import operator

possibleOperators = [
    "Addition",
    "Subtraction",
    "Division",
    "Multiplication",
    ]

num1 = input("Input a number:\n")
if num1.isdigit():
    pass
else:
    print(f"\n'{num1}' is not a number")
    num1 = input("\nInput a number:\n")

op = input("\nPlease choose an operator:\nAddition\nSubtraction\nMultiplication\nDivision\n\n")
if op.title() not in possibleOperators:
    print(f"\n'{op}' is an invalid operator")
    op = input("\nPlease choose an operator:\nAddition\nSubtraction\nMultiplication\nDivision\n\n")


num2 = input("\nInput a second number:\n")
if num2.isdigit():
    pass
else:
    print(f"\n'{num2}' is not a number")
    num2 = input("\nInput a number:\n")

if op == possibleOperators[0]:
    answr = operator.add(num1, num2)
    print(answr)
elif op == possibleOperators[1]:
    answr = operator.sub(num1, num2)
    print(answr)
elif op == possibleOperators[2]:
    answr = operator.truediv(num1, num2)
    print(answr)
elif op == possibleOperators[3]:
    answr = operator.mul(num1, num2)
    print(answr)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You did not declare num1 and num2 as int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is because you are not changing the `num2` and `num2` to int.

```py
import operator

possibleOperators = [
    "Addition",
    "Subtraction",
    "Division",
    "Multiplication",
    ]

num1 = input("Input a number:\n")
if num1.isdigit():
    num1 = int(num1)
else:
    print(f"\n'{num1}' is not a number")
    num1 = int(input("\nInput a number:\n"))

op = input("\nPlease choose an operator:\nAddition\nSubtraction\nMultiplication\nDivision\n\n")
if op.title() not in possibleOperators:
    print(f"\n'{op}' is an invalid operator")
    op = input("\nPlease choose an operator:\nAddition\nSubtraction\nMultiplication\nDivision\n\n")


num2 = input("\nInput a second number:\n")
if num2.isdigit():
    num2 = int(num2)
else:
    print(f"\n'{num2}' is not a number")
    num2 = int(input("\nInput a number:\n"))

if op == possibleOperators[0]:
    answr = operator.add(num1, num2)
    print(answr)
elif op == possibleOperators[1]:
    answr = operator.sub(num1, num2)
    print(answr)
elif op == possibleOperators[2]:
    answr = operator.truediv(num1, num2)
    print(answr)
elif op == possibleOperators[3]:
    answr = operator.mul(num1, num2)
    print(answr)
```

You can also use this code.

```py
import operator

possibleOperators = {
    "Addition":operator.add,
    "Subtraction":operator.sub,
    "Division":operator.truediv,
    "Multiplication":operator.mul
    }

while True:
    num1 = input("Input first number:\n")
    if num1.isdigit():
        num1 = int(num1)
        break
    print(f"{num} is not integer")

while True:
    op = input("\nPlease choose an operator:\nAddition\nSubtraction\nMultiplication\nDivision\n\n").title()
    if op in possibleOperators:
        break
    print(f"\n'{op}' is an invalid operator")

while True:
    num2 = input("Input second number:\n")
    if num2.isdigit():
        num2 = int(num2)
        break
    print(f"{num} is not integer")



ans = possibleOperators[op](num1,num2)
print(ans)
```

There is another way but it is complicated.

```py
import operator

possibleOperators = {
    "Addition":operator.add,
    "Subtraction":operator.sub,
    "Division":operator.truediv,
    "Multiplication":operator.mul
    }

def func(string,isoperator=False):

    while True:
        result = input(string)
        if isoperator:
            if result.title() in possibleOperators:
                result = result.title()
                break
        else:
            if result.isdigit():
                result = int(result)
                break
        print(f"\n'{result}' is an invalid operator")

    return result

num1 = func(string="Input first number:\n")
op = func(string="\nPlease choose an operator:\nAddition\nSubtraction\nMultiplication\nDivision\n\n",isoperator=True)
num2 = func(string="Input second number:\n")
ans = possibleOperators[op](num1,num2)
print(f"\nThe answer is {ans}")
```